# Test to see if 2 inputs are empty together with jQuery Bassistance

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm using Bassistance jQuery validation plugin and i need to test if 2 inputs are empty, if so then show an error message, else if one of the two fields is completed then that is fine.

This is the form fields:

```
<label for="para_comp_name">Your name *</label>
<input id="para_comp_name" name="para_comp_name" type="text" value="">

<label for="para_comp_code">Inside track unique code *</label>
<input id="para_comp_code" name="para_comp_code" type="text" value="">

<label for="para_comp_message">Message</label>
<textarea id="para_comp_message" name="para_comp_message" cols="" rows=""></textarea>

<label for="para_comp_image">Upload image</label>
<input id="para_comp_image" name="para_comp_image" type="file" value="" size="16">
```

Only the fields which are required are the name and unique code, a user can then either fill in either or both the message and image fields.
I just need to validate if they are both empty together.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom validation method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod("custom-rule", function() {
        return $('#para_comp_message').val().trim() + 
               $('#para_comp_image').val().trim() != '';
    }, "custom message");

    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            para_comp_name: "required",
            para_comp_code: "required",
            para_comp_image: "custom-rule"
        }
    });

});​
```

Try the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y7MQc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

this would normally be :

```
if (! $('#para_comp_name').val() && ! $('#otherFieldHere').val()){
 // do something f it's empty
}else{
 // do something else if it's not empty
}
```